# Windows authentication for react api calls

Tags: reactjs, windows, authentication

I am new to this thus I want to know how to use automatic Windows login details as the credentials for React app API calls.

My backend API uses my windows credentials for successful API calls and rendering in the react app. I have hard-coded it currently for all the API calls.

I want to push my react app to production and it needs to get the user details from windows login automatically and make the API calls for the specific user.

How do I do it?

I have checked other questions but could not understand what fits my requirement.

Comment: It's driven by your backend.  If no authentication is passed in the original request your backend should respond with a 401 and authentication schemes that it accepts, at which point any modern browser will automatically send the request again with the appropriate authentication information.  What platform is your backend?

Comment: Its Java-Spring based